# django 1.6.5 password reset email check validlink

Tags: python, django

I am follwing the exact steps in this [blog](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html).

also made the changes:

```
1) the url template tag syntax as noted above by "F L" 
2) uidb36 in the urls.py and email template both should be uidb64 per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#django-contrib-auth-password-reset-uses-base-64-encoding-of-user-pk
```

When I enter the email address, I get the mail and after entering the url: http://localhost:8000/user/password/reset/NDI-47h-e1fbd1df48ce2aa05de4/, I always get  the message:

```
Password reset unsuccessful
The password reset link was invalid, 
possibly because it has already been used. 
Please request a new password reset.
```

i.e the validlink always fails. Why?

Sharing relevant Code blocks: urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       url(r'^user/password/reset/$', 
                           'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', 
                           {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/reset/done/'}, name="password_reset"),
                       (r'^user/password/reset/done/$',
                        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
                       (r'^user/password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 
                        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', 
                        {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/done/'}),
                       (r'^user/password/done/$', 
                        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

In my template folder, created a folder called registration: The structure of my template folder:
/templates$ find

```
.
./registration
./registration/password_reset_form.html
./registration/password_reset_confirm.html
./registration/password_reset_email.html
./registration/password_reset_done.html
./registration/password_reset_complete.html
./admin
```

password_reset_email.html:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% comment %}
{% load url from future %}
{% endcomment %}
{% autoescape off %}

You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ 'http' }}://{{ 'localhost:8000' }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}

Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.username }}

Thanks for using our site!

The {{ site_name }} team.
```

All other templates as in the [blog](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html)

Comment: Sharing your `urls.py` code and any other relevant code might be helpful.

Comment: @TreyHunner updated with code snippets. kindly help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the `-` in your URL is a problem because your first regular expression group matches `-`'s greedily.

Notice that `-` is matched by that first regular expression but you're *also* using it as a delimiter.

Instead of this URL pattern:

```
r'^user/password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$'
```

Try this one:

```
r'^user/password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$'
```

The difference is that we changed the `-` in between the matching groups to a `/`, which is a character not matched within the first group.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Trey Hunner, that was a very minute change which could not have been traced so easily. Hope this post helps others also